# Kivy stencil view limits

Tags: python, kivy

Nesting some widget inside a scroll view gave me this error

```
 Exception Exception: Exception('Cannot push more than 8 level of stencil. (stack overflow)',) in 'kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions.StencilPush.apply' ignored
```

I'm aware that more than 8 eight stencil-aware objects can't be stacked; but I'd like to know what does this mean practically: I've stacked more than 8 interactive object inside a Layout before that, but this time wouldn't work.

My code is quite long so I can't write it in here, it's a complicate nesting of different type of widgets which are managing their different interactions. I'd like to know if this limitation of the stencil view is giving me limits on the use of kivy or it could be a bad managing made from me.

[EDIT]

Here is the widget layout that use the scroll view

```
class Edit_area(ScrollView):

    def __init__(self,**kw):
        super(Edit_area, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.scroll_area_wrapper = Widget()
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')
        self.graph = Graph(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Posizione',
        x_ticks_major=100, y_ticks_major=2,
        y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=0,
        x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=0, xmax=1000, ymin=0, ymax=10, draw_border = True)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.graph)
        self.scroll_area_wrapper.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.line = Editable_line()
        self.scroll_area_wrapper.add_widget(self.line)

        self.add_widget(self.scroll_area_wrapper)
```

Because the scrollView accept only one widget, I've used a wrapper to add all the element.
Furthermore the element 'line' has more other widget inside it like 'point' and 'spline points'. Graph is the class of the kivy-garden graph package

Comment: Can you post your widget layout?

Comment: I've posted the declaration of the class which implement the scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I wrote some bad code that was trying to instantiate more stencil view inside each other.

I understood that the limit of the stencil view is related purely to scrollview (and the stencilView class itself of course) because it's the only one to inherit this class.

So you can't instantiate more than 8 scrollview inside each other, which seems perfectly fine.

```
class stencilTest(App):
     def build(self):
        super(stencilTest, self).__init__()
        root = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        r = root
        for i in range(10):
            w = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1), size=(1000, 800))
            r.add_widget(w)
            r = r.children[0]       
        return root


if __name__ == "__main__":
     stencilTest().run()
```

This code will reproduce the error if interested